# Is there a graphical interface for archive compression in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, compression, zip, 7zip

On Windows, I have used the program 7zip for nearly all of my compression tasks in the past. Now, after switching to Ubuntu, I also installed this program from the Software Center. After completion, I was able to select the .7z-format from the archive-creation menu, however I can not find any compression options, just the possibility of encrypting the file table and a password prompt. In the Windows build of the program, there are many more options, such as library size and thread usage, but I have not yet been able to find such a menu in Ubuntu.

Is there a way to make these options available in the integrated archive manager or an alternative one that provides them?

I am aware that it is possible to define these options in the terminal, but I would prefer to have an interface that lets me see all possible choices and interactively calculates memory usages.

If another library than 7zip offers these options under Ubuntu, I would be willing to try that one, as long as it is F/OSS. Platform compatibility is not impotant, just quickly selectable options for different tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great choice is `peazip` which has most of the options that you are after. Although it is not yet in the Ubuntu Repositories it can be *relatively* easily installed. I have tested a *32bit* `peazip` on a *64bit* Trusty Tahr installation (hence the addition of 32bit libraries) as follows.

I could not find an easy installation of a pure *64bit* `peazip` unfortunately although I saw a 'portable` version that seemed to be 64bit at least in parts. I did not test this although this is certainly an option...

This is a single command:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar libpango1.0-0:i386 \
libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libxft2:i386 && \
wget --content-disposition \
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/peazip/6.0.0/peazip_6.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i peazip_6.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb
```

On a clean installation of Trusty there may will still be some dependencies required so if `dpkg` complains that it could not configure `peazip` run the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i peazip_6.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb
```

The options you are after are in the 'Advanced' section:

[image]

and the addition of passwords is easily available from the main menu under Tools --> Password Manager:

[image]

Integration with Nautilus requires another step: copy the scripts shipped with `peazip` to the correct location and make them executable:

```
cp -v /usr/local/share/PeaZip/FreeDesktop_integration/nautilus-scripts/Archiving/PeaZip/* \
      $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/{"Add to Archive","Extract Archive","Extract Here","Extract to Folder","Open Archive"}
```

Log out and then back in, then Nautilus integration works well:

[image]

License details are contained in the link in my 'References' but seems to be GNU Lesser General Public License...

**References:**

- [Peazip: How to encode archives with password](http://www.peazip.org/encrypt-files.html#encrypt_file)
- [Peazip for Linux](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html)
- [PEAZIP PROJECT TOS, PRIVACY](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-tos-privacy.html)

Comment: Wow, `peazip` is great. Doesn't have a memory usage predictor, but it's got all options from normal 7-zip. Thx for info! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal Windows version. I'm currently using `7z1514-x64.exe`. It works perfectly on WINE and performance is as good as on Windows. Not sure about that F/OSS though... Haven't seen any satisfying Linux-specific app for this.

Comment: 7z is F/OSS - it's licensed GPLv2.