# GUI file compressors

Tags: files

What GUI file compressors are available for Ubuntu ?

I prefer one that offers LZMA2 to speed up file compression since I have multiple cores.

Thanks.

Comment: peazip is a nice one: http://askubuntu.com/q/757792/57576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File Roller is Ubuntu's default application for handling the creation, modification and extraction of archives.

To launch it by itself, press Alt+F2 and type file-roller.

The following archive formats are well supported, and installed by default in File Roller:

tar - gzip - bzip - bzip2 - LZMA - zip - jar - iso